# FLP Impossiblity Result assumption of C_1 = e'(C_0)

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, consensus

[FLP86](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/jacm85.pdf)'s famous proof regarding impossibility of solving consensus in a asynchronous distributed system (even with only a single failure) assumes, in the proof of the third lemma, the existence of an event `e'`, such that the neighbor configurations `C0` and `C1` can be related as `C1 = e'(C0)`.

I don't get how this is possible, as this seems to me like `e'` carries out a state transition from a 0-valent configuration to a 1-valent configuration. Further, the proof of case 1 of lemma 3 clearly states that any successor of any 0-valent configuration has to be a 0-valent configuration. What am I missing here?

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15131730/3924118) do not answer the above question. That other question is relates to the proof of existence of `C0` and `C1` and not that of `e'`.

Comment: Probably better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, C0 is not 0-valent, C1 is not 1-valent. It is quite confusing for the two symbols.